# Eager loading individual entry from User table and associated belongs_to records using ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Is it possible to eager load a specific entry from the user table, as well as all associated tables attached via `belong_to`.

For example, I have `users` table with `accounts` and `patients` tables, that both `belong_to :user`. If I wanted to grab a specific User table entry and eager_load the associated tables, akin to something like this:

```
user = User.find_by_email("testemail@here.com").eager_load(:accounts, :patients)
```

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.  Try putting the associations in an array within the eager_load call as shown below:

```
user = User.includes([:accounts, :patients]).find_by(email: "testemail@here.com")
```

Now that you have included the associated tables and then found your user you can call any attributes from those other tables on the user without firing another query from the database.  For example once that is run you can do:

```
all_user_accounts = user.accounts
```

This will not fire a query in the database but instead be loaded from memory.

If you use #eager_load you are doing one query whereas includes will do it in one or two depending on what it deems necessary. So what is #includes for? It decides for you which way it is going to be. You let Rails handle that decision.

Check this guide for great information on includes/eager_load/preload in rails:
http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/

Comment: When I execute this from irb or rails console, I get the same error I did with the normal find_by_email: –  NoMethodError: undefined method `includes' for #<User:0x00000005e0dda0>

Comment: You need to make sure you're using includes on the class itself and not an instance of it.  User.includes = good whereas user.includes = bad!  Try it again and let me know if you get the same error.

Comment: The includes method is looking to load the associated tables (accounts and patients) with the User table first so you must do it as I have instead of finding a record first and then loading associated tables.  First you include the associated tables of the User table, then you find the record and can call any attributes from the associated tables you just included without firing another database query.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. Would using .includes or .eager_load result in the fewest number of SQL queries?

Comment: Includes will handle it in either one or two queries depending on what Rails thinks is appropriate.  Eager_load will do it in one but fail depending on the situation.  In general stick to inlcudes and check out the info in the link at the bottom of my post when you get time to learn more.